Best JDBC driver to pick for Oracle 19c and JDK 11
The differences between the JDBC drivers supporting Oracle 19c isn't fully clear to me. I am running an application on Red Hat with OpenJDK 11.0.24 and I seem to have the following options:

Oracle Database 23ai (23.6.0.24.10) JDBC Driver & UCP Downloads: Supports Oracle Database versions - 23ai, 21c, and 19c = ojdbc8.jar (JDBC 4.2), ojdbc11.jar (JDBC 4.3)
Oracle Database 19c (19.25.0.0) JDBC Driver & UCP Downloads - Long Term Release: Supports Oracle Database versions - 21c, 19c, 18c, and 12.2.= ojdbc8.jar (JDBC 4.2), ojdbc10.jar (JDBC 4.3)

Questions:

For JDK 11 and Oracle 19c, is there any reason not to opt for the jdbc11.jar over 8 and 10?
Are there any performance implications of JDBC 4.3 over JDBC 4.2?


Section 3.1 Summary of New Features in the JDBC 4.3 spec.

Both 19c (19.25.0.0) and 23ai (23.6.0.24.10) drivers are supported with Oracle Database 19c. 23ai JDBC driver is the most recent release, hence it has more features than 19c and to answer your question:

As you are already using JDK11, hence it is better to use ojdbc11.jar which is compiled with JDK11. ojdbc8.jar is meant for those who are still using JDK8 and because of that they cannot use the ojdbc11.jar.
No  performance implications of JDBC 4.3 over JDBC 4.2.


Thanks for taking the time to answer such a noob question. I certainly had a tendency to certain assumptions, but your answers were needed to clear those up.
